# Subgroup not corresponding to an intermediate field

Tags: galois-theory

Consider the Galois extension $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1}, \sqrt{p_2},\ldots)$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ where $p_1<p_2<\cdots$ are positive primes.

Then $\mbox{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is $(\mathbb{Z}/2)\times (\mathbb{Z}/2)\times \cdots$ (countable infinite direct product).

This group has uncountable subgroups of order $2$.

**Q.** Can we explicitly find a subgroup of order $2$ which is not equal to $\mbox{Gal}(E/F)$ for some $\mathbb{Q}\subset F \subset E$ (and $[E:F]=2$)?

---

Any automorphism in $\mbox{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ will take $\sqrt{p}_i$ to $\pm \sqrt{p_i}$. I took the automorphism $\sigma$ which takes $\sqrt{p}_i$ to $-\sqrt{p_i}$ for all $i$. Then I thought that if $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_ip_{i+1}}:i=1,2,\ldots)$ then $[E:F]=2$ and this is fixed field of $\langle\sigma\rangle$. So  $\langle\sigma\rangle$ **corresponds** to some intermediate field.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/how-to-describe-the-galois-group-of-the-compositum-of-all-quadratic-extensions-o in fact the majority of the finite index subgroups are not closed.

Comment: Why $[E:F]=2$ in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main theorem of infinite Galois theory states that if $L/K$ is a Galois extension, then $E \mapsto \mathrm{Gal}(L/E)$ provides an order-reversing bijection between the intermediate fields of $L/K$ and the closed subgroups of the topological group $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$. Moreover, $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is a Hausdorff topological group, so that in particular all finite subgroups $H$ are closed, and they have the form $\mathrm{Gal}(L/E)$ for some finite $L/E$ with $[L:E] = \mathrm{ord}(H)$. Namely, we can take $E = L^H$.

This answers your special case affirmatively.